# How do I rewrite URL that has custom parameter

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules, parameter

I'm stuck on rewriting my url. been searching for days hacking code together but to no avail - So looking for help now.

My url is:

```
https://domainname.com/topic/ux-process/?type=newsletter
```

I want the URL to be:

```
https://domainname.com/topic/ux-process/type/newsletter
```

("topic" is a custom taxonomy)

This post seemed the most concise but couldn't get it to work

https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/custom-page-template-page-based-on-url-rewrite--wp-30564

Help getting this working would make my day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [rewrite endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_endpoint/) for this.

The first step is to give your custom taxonomy an endpoint mask when you register the taxonomy:

```
$args = [
    'rewrite' => [
        'slug' => 'topic',
        'ep_mask' => EP_CATEGORIES
    ],
    // the rest of your args...
];
register_taxonomy( 'topic', array( 'post' ), $args );
```

The next step is to add the endpoint. This should be hooked to run on `init`, just like your taxonomy registration code.

```
add_rewrite_endpoint( 'type', EP_CATEGORIES );
```

Don't forget to flush rewrite rules after adding this code. The easiest way to do this is by visiting the Settings > Permalinks page.

You should now be able to add `type/newsletter` onto the end of your taxonomy links. To access the passed value, use `get_query_var`:

```
$type = get_query_var( 'type', false );
```

If the code currently expects to find `type` in `$_GET['type']` and you can't change that, you can manually set that value before the code that tries to access it:

```
$_GET['type'] = get_query_var( 'type', false );
```